# Cannot update html text from script in php echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have some code like this:

```
<?php
   echo "<script> alert('hello world!!!'); </script>";
   echo "<script> document.getElementById('updatetext').innerHTML='heyatest'; </script>";
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="updatetext">Some Text Here</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need it to work this way and update the text at certain point through PHP code. In above the alert popup shows, but my text does not get updated with "heyatest"

Comment: Because you have it before the document has even been created, look at your console you will have error mesages

Comment: updated by/with what?

Comment: @ Patrick: hi, how can I fix this? I am new to php. @Funk updated

Comment: see the answer given

Comment: You don't need multiple `<script>` tags, unless you are using multiple external JavaScript pages. You should use external JavaScript in the `<head>`, with a load Event, like: `var old = onload; onload = function(evtObj){ if(old)old(); /* change old var name if using technique on other page */ /* put your code in here */ }` or `addEventListener('load', function(evtObj){ /*put your code in here */ });`. External script with the `.js` extension allows the page to be cached. If building JavaScript with PHP, you can use a `.php` extension for JavaScript pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the javascript that tries to find your id updatetext before that object exists.  It cannot find it.  Call the php after the html object you're looking for.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="updatetext">Some Text Here</p>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
   echo "<script> alert('hello world!!!'); </script>";
   echo "<script> document.getElementById('updatetext').innerHTML='heyatest'; </script>";
?>
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript isn't calling an initiated object. Try it like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="updatetext">Some Text Here</p>
        <?php
           echo "<script> alert('hello world!!!'); </script>";
           echo "<script> document.getElementById('updatetext').innerHTML='heyatest'; </script>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```